# Loading multiple Google Fonts in 1 request violates HTML standards

Tags: html, url, w3c-validation, google-font-api

In [Google Fonts documentation](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started), it suggests that loading multiple Google Fonts can be done via pipe character (`|`), for example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700|Amaranth:400italic" />
```

With [HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/), it said:

> Bad value http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700|Amaranth:400italic for attribute href on element link: Illegal character in query: | is not allowed.

Which website should I trust? Of course I can separate two fonts in two requests as follow, but the load time will be doubled.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amaranth:400italic" />
```

p.s. the DOCTYPE is HTML5.

Comment: ... or you can just URL encode it.

Comment: Thanks for posting this and sorry the checker message isn’t more helpful here. But going forward I hope [the small improvement I just made to the error message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35788033/loading-multiple-google-fonts-in-1-request-violates-html-standards#comment-59252779) helps others figure out what they need to change in order to avoid that error being raised by the checker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @BoltClock suggests, escaping the pipe character to `%7C` is the best choice.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700%7CAmaranth:400italic" />
```

Both fonts loaded correctly, and verified by the network response of the above link.

Comment: For future reference, [the URL Standard](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/) [specifies the list of code points that don’t need to be percent-encoded](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#url-code-points). It calls those characters *URL code points*. So if you look at that list you’ll see that the only common non-alphanumeric characters (where by “common” I just mean in the ASCII range) that don’t need to be percent-encoded in URLs are `! $ & ' ( ) * +  - . / : ; = ? @ _ ~`

Comment: I just now pushed an update to https://checker.html5.org/ and https://validator.w3.org/nu/ such that for this `Illegal character` case, the error message now includes the message *Common non-alphanumeric characters other than `! $ & ' ( ) * +  - . / : ; = ? @ _ ~` generally must be [percent-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). For example, the pipe character (`|`) must be encoded as `%7C`*. I think that will make it easier for others to figure out how to deal with this when they run into the same error message.

Comment: on the other hand, validator.w3.org/nu wrongly identifies `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />` as: `Element link is missing required attribute property.`, but `<link>` tag has no such attribute.

Comment: If you’re seeing that message for that `link` element, I think it must be because you have the `link` element in the `body` rather than `head`. The HTML spec normally doesn’t allow `link` in `body`. But one case where the element is allowed in the body is if it has a `property` element, as defined in the [HTML+RDFa 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-rdfa/) spec. And the checker supports checking against the HTML+RDFa 1.1 requirements (in addition to the core requirements in the HTML spec); otherwise the error message would just say the `link` element isn’t allowed at all where you have it, ever.

Comment: @sideshowbarker thanks for the explanation. Yes, the `<link>` tag is in `<body>` in testing phase. will move back to `<head>`.

Comment: You don’t actually need to move that `<link>` back to the `<head>`—because we just this week [landed a change to the HTML spec that allows `link[rel=stylesheet]` and other “body-ok” rel keywords in the body](https://github.com/whatwg/html/commit/179983e9eb99efe417349a40ebb664bd11668ddd). The checker is just not yet caught up with that, though I have [raised an issue for implementing the “body-ok” support in the checker](https://github.com/validator/validator/issues/253) and will try to land that soon.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**: rephrased to properly communicate the position with the degree of nuance intended (earlier phrasing may have misrepresented my position as "never use validators" when, in fact, my intention was "choose browser behavior over validators in the event of disagreement").

In this particular case, the validator is correct; the '|' symbol needs to be percent-encoded. However, you should keep in mind that validators are not perfect and that many of them are overly strict  in their processing; **what really matters** is **how the website loads in the browsers that your users use**, not what a particular validator happens to think. If there is a disagreement between a validator and what experimentation in browsers shows is the case, the browser is always "correct" from the standpoint of website development (it may not be correct vis-a-vis what is captured in W3C standards, but "the web platform" is dictated by de-facto "standards" arising from typical browser behavior... W3C and other standards committees are often well behind browser changes and only fully, formally standardize aspects of the web platform well after it has already been widely adopted).

As @slideshowbarker notes in the comments below, validators and linters can be helpful in the development process to catch errors early on in development (and on this I agree). However, you should be aware that [validators are just a tool](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/validation.html) (and not always correct or sometimes overly noisy); it's important not to waste a significant amount of time making validators happy on code that browsers perfectly accept. And you certainly shouldn't litter your website with validation icons/buttons that simply confuse users who visit the website and don't know or care about the details of HTML.

Because browsers, not validators, are the true "source of truth" for whether a page is behaving properly, in addition to some of these other validator tools, you may wish to add [WebDriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) tests to your tool arsenal. WebDriver allows you to create integration tests that render your website in various different browsers, which allows you to simulate and  verify your website's behavior in various browsers in a much more accurate fashion than standalone validators do. The checks performed by your WebDriver tests are therefore also likely to be more important / less noisy / less ignorable than errors raised by a validator (which may sometimes be overly stringent in their complaints).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I do think validator exists for a reason. In my opinion, it's very important for all websites to follow the standards, otherwise the Internet will become a mess, and against-standard products like Internet Explorer will continue to destroy the overall Internet quality.

Comment: Maintainer of the W3C/Nu HTML Checker here. I actually agree with the statements here about “validators”. That’s why the HTML Checker isn’t a validator. Instead it’s just a tool for helping you catch unintended mistakes you might otherwise miss. I also completely agree that what really matters is how your documents load in the browsers your users use, and the behavior of the documents once they’re rendered. But it’s not an either-or. In any programming environment, static analysis is also useful, and that’s why we have linters and that’s basically what the HTML checker is, a linter.

Comment: But the difference with the HTML Checker is，the linting it does isn’t just based on someone’s whims about what the rules should be—instead it’s based on rules we have wide agreement about, and documented in a standard spec—[the HTML Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/). And the HTML Standard actually itself also documents the rationale for its rules．For more on that，see https://checker.html5.org/about.html#why-validate & https://www.w3.org/TR/html/introduction.html#syntax-errors & https://www.w3.org/TR/html/introduction.html#restrictions-on-content-models-and-on-attribute-values

Comment: Finally, I want to add that a large part of what the HTML Checker provides is basically datatype checking—syntax checking. The datatype/syntax of some HTML attributes, like [the `srcset` attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#attr-img-srcset), is complicated and extremely error-prone, so without tools that can help check it for you, it’s easy to make mistakes that without a checker to help you can sometimes be very hard to find. So my aim for the HTML checker is for it to save you time—save you from wasting your time—by helping you catch those kind of mistakes.

Comment: @sideshowbarker, I agree that validators are useful tools, but -- as I'm sure you already know from your own experience -- they can often produce false positives that really require no action. I can see how my earlier version seemed much more hardline than I intended, however.... I've since rephrased. I was intending to address the larger question of "when there is disagreement, which do I trust". Given the number of websites with validator icons or wasted time being XHTML valid, it's still worth pointing out that validation is just a tool.

Comment: @Raptor preventing non-standard browsers is the purpose of web platform tests (https://github.com/w3c/web-platform-tests) which validate browser compliance/agreement (and which most major browsers now use to exercise their own browsers). Testing browsers for compliance is much more sensible than testing individual website against a standard that is actually not accurate to true browser behavior.